# how open transform xml file that is in my project folder in Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, xml, react-native, rect

I'm new to react native. I'm trying to transform an xml file into a Javascript object for parse it after. My problem is that I am not able to pass at readFile method, the path of my project folder.
I'm using react-native-fs module, in this mode:

```
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs'),
    xml2js = require('react-native-xml2js');
parser = new xml2js.Parser()
RNFS.readFile(what path?, (err, data) ->
     parser.parseString data, (err, result) ->
        console.dir result
        console.log 'Done.'
```

Someone can help me?
thanks.

P.s.
My project structure is:

```
Myapp
|--->App
|     |--->Components
|          |--->Xml
|--->Android
|--->``Ios
...
```

How can I reference xml folder in my code?

Answer (score 0):

there are APIs in 'react-native-fs'/FS.common.js to get directory paths.for example:DocumentDirectoryPath, ExternalStorageDirectoryPath, ExternalDirectoryPath etc.

it depends on where the file is

read file in the bundle on Android. use

```
RNFS.readFileAssets("a/b/c.txt")
```

read file in the app own director on Android and iOS, use

```
RNFS.readFile(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + "/a/b/c.txt")
```

read file in sdcard on Android, use

```
RNFS.readFile(RNFS.ExternalDirectoryPath + "/a/b/c.txt")
```

Comment: In first, thanks for your answer. I've another question. I've already tasted the RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath method, but inside this folder I haven't found my folder with xml file. I've just updated my ask with an example of my folder structure. I would reference the xml folder